# How to merge multiple mp4 files as chapters in a final mp4?

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc, merge, video-encoding

I have folder with files named like `0001.mp4`, `0002.mp4`, ...
I want to merge all these files to a `combined.mp4`, and I want it to have an internal chapter marks. It is convenient when playing for example in vlc, as you can see the chapter names in timeline.

[image]

How can I make such `combined.mp4`? Preferably, command line script using `ffmpeg`, and no additional dependencies.

There is [similar](https://superuser.com/q/724459/873855) question, but asker wants to use handbrake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chapters info is stored in file metadata. Ffmpeg allows to export metadata to file, and load metadata from file. Documentation is here: [ffmpeg metadata 1](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Metadata-1)

Now we need to prepare a metadata file, that we will use for combined.mp4. And we can do this in one go, without the need to first make combined file from all files, and then another file but with injected metadata. We save storage space.

I have made a python script `multiple_mp4_to_single_mp4_with_chapters.py` that does the job:

```py
import subprocess
import os
import re


def make_chapters_metadata(list_mp4: list):
    print(f"Making metadata source file")

    chapters = {}
    for single_mp4 in list_mp4:
        number = single_mp4.removesuffix(".mp4")
        duration_in_microseconds = int((subprocess.run(f"ffprobe -v quiet -of csv=p=0 -show_entries format=duration {folder}/{single_mp4}", shell=True, capture_output=True).stdout.decode().strip().replace(".", "")))
        chapters[number] = {"duration": duration_in_microseconds}

    chapters["0001"]["start"] = 0
    for n in range(1, len(chapters)):
        chapter = f"{n:04d}"
        next_chapter = f"{n + 1:04d}"
        chapters[chapter]["end"] = chapters[chapter]["start"] + chapters[chapter]["duration"]
        chapters[next_chapter]["start"] = chapters[chapter]["end"] + 1
    last_chapter = f"{len(chapters):04d}"
    chapters[last_chapter]["end"] = chapters[last_chapter]["start"] + chapters[last_chapter]["duration"]

    metadatafile = f"{folder}/combined.metadata.txt"
    with open(metadatafile, "w+") as m:
        m.writelines(";FFMETADATA1\n")
        for chapter in chapters:
            ch_meta = """
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000000
START={}
END={}
title={}
""".format(chapters[chapter]["start"], chapters[chapter]["end"], chapter)
            m.writelines(ch_meta)


def concatenate_all_to_one_with_chapters():
    print(f"Concatenating list of mp4 to combined.mp4")
    metadatafile = f"{folder}/combined.metadata.txt"
    os.system(f"ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -y -f concat -i list_mp4.txt -i {metadatafile} -map_metadata 1 combined.mp4")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    folder = "."  # Specify folder where the files 0001.mp4... are

    list_mp4 = [f for f in os.listdir(folder) if re.match(r'[0-9]{4}\.mp4', f)]
    list_mp4.sort()

    # Make the list of mp4 in ffmpeg format
    if os.path.isfile("list_mp4.txt"):
        os.remove("list_mp4.txt")
    for filename_mp4 in list_mp4:
        with open("list_mp4.txt", "a") as f:
            line = f"file '{filename_mp4}'\n"
            f.write(line)

    make_chapters_metadata(list_mp4)
    concatenate_all_to_one_with_chapters()
```

Now you can place it to the folder with your mp4 files (or edit the `folder` variable in script), and run it:

```bash
$ ls
0001.mp4 0002.mp4 0003.mp4 0004.mp4 multiple_mp4_to_single_mp4_with_chapters.py
$ python multiple_mp4_to_single_mp4_with_chapters.py
```

Now you will have the `combined.mp4`, and when it's opened in vlc, you will see chapter marks.

---

I saw a script on bash that does it with mp4box and mp4chaps: [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3cf94440d47d23e11ba3d56ec2b280ca)
Also there is bash version without such dependencies: [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bdurrow/b51470869dd72b2333407dbfcb947801)
And another version on python, but it creates merged file twice: [this gist](https://gist.github.com/palaniraja/d14ba9ac49019526e0774b28e2d71b16?permalink_comment_id=3260780#gistcomment-3260780)

Comment: I feel like my comment got read, it works like a charm today! I simply wish we could name the chapters differently but it's easy with ChapterEditor, thank you for that script. It should be marked as the answer!

Comment: GPLing by changes https://gist.github.com/tom-huntington/1323af4b991ca34ef4a46b3e44532ada